# Mouse cursor disapparing in full screen app

Tags: windows, cursor

On at least one but possibly more Windows 8 machines, the hardware cursor remained invisible while in full screen mode.  This was on customers' machines, so we haven't been able to investigate their configurations.

I've been trying to reproduce the problem, and I found that on Windows 7, if I have **pointer trails** enabled, the cursor indeed disappears when running our app full screen.

I'd like to declare this issue solved -- just advise users to disable cursor trails if they run into this problem again.  But I want to know if there's something more at work: what exactly about pointer trails is causing them to not get drawn over a full screen app, and are there other settings that could have the same effect?  That wasn't a terribly obscure setting (though it is definitely showing its age), so I'm worried there might be other configurations that will have the same effect.